# In 2D array A[m][n], how value of A is same as *A?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

What I know about 2D array:

1. In array the array name is pointer to first element's address
2. Here we can think A as array of array, so A would point to 0th 1D array
3. So A+i would point to ith element of A
4. *(A+i) would point to first element of ith element of A
5. Then in 2D array A+i address value should be same as *(A+i)

But this doesn't make sense to me how A value is same as of *A, can someone tell me how this is working in memory, I know it is correct but I can't explain it to myself

Comment: How was `A` declared?

Comment: `int A[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12} };` I dont know if this makes difference

Comment: It does; it means #4 is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

> In array the array name is pointer to first element's address

is *wrong*.

For any array, its symbol by itself will *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

So for your array `A` it will decay to `&A[0]`.

If you dereference that pointer, as what happens with `*A`, then you have `*(&A[0])`. Which is the same as plain `A[0]`.

Since your array `A` is an array of arrays, then `A[0]` is an array, which will in turn also decay to a pointer to its first element. So `A[0]` will decay to `&A[0][0]`.

So `*A` will be the same as `&A[0][0]`.

There are however a big different in *types* for the different pointers.

Take your example array:

```
int A[3][4];
```

Then `&A[0]` will be a pointer to an array of four `int` values, or `int (*)[4]`. And `&A[0][0]` will be a pointer to a single `int` value, or `int *`.

---

Now to why all these pointers seems to be the same, it's because they are all pointing to the very same location, which also happens to be the same location as the array itself (i.e. `&A`, which will have the type `int (*)[3][4]`).

If we "draw" it, it will look something like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| A[0][0] | A[0][1] | A[0][2] | A[0][3] | A[1][0] | A[1][1] | ... |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
^
|
&A
|
&A[0]
|
&A[0][0]
```

As you can see, all three pointers will point to the same location, but as mentioned have different types.

Answer (score 2):

"In array the array name is pointer to first element's address."  That's not really true.  Time to forget you ever heard it.  It's partly true, and it might be a helpful explanation under certain limited circumstances, but sooner or later, it causes far more confusion than any useful explanation it might have provided.

The real truth is this: *When you ask for the "value" of an array in an expression, what you get is a pointer to its first element.*

So for any array `A`, if you try to print its value like this:

```
printf("%p\n", A);
```

what you'll see is a pointer to the array's first element.

But you've got a two-dimensional array.  So if you ask for `A`, you get a pointer to the array's first element.  But what happens when you ask for `*A`?

Well, if `A` got you a pointer to the array's first element, then `*A` gets you the "contents" of that pointer, which *is* the first element of the array, which is... another array!

And if you try to take the value of ''that'' array, by saying

```
printf("%p\n", *A);
```

what you get is a pointer to *that* array's first element.

And as I think you can see, for a two dimensional array, a pointer to the whole array will be the same as a pointer to the first row in the array, which will be the same as a pointer to the first element of the first row of the array.

---

The rest of this may be a little confusing at first.  I said, "When you ask for the "value" of an array in an expression, what you get is a pointer to its first element."  More formally, what this means that in an expression, when you refer to `A`, it is 100% completely and totally the same as if you had said `&A[0]`.

So since `*` sort of undoes the effect of a `&`, when you say `*A`, it is 100% completely and totally the same as if you had said `A[0]`.

The above is true for any kind of an array.  For a two-dimensional array, things can get more interesting.

First of all, for a two-dimensional array, when we look at `*A` or `A[0]`, either of those refers to *another* array -- the two-dimensional array's first row.

So `A` gets you a pointer to `A`'s first element, which is another array.
And `*A` gets you a pointer to the first row's first element, which is an actual cell.
So the expressions `A` and `*A` will have the same pointer value, *but* they have different types!
The first one has type "pointer to array of whatever", while the second one has type "pointer to whatever".

See also [question 6.12](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array then its designator used in expressions with rare exceptions (as for example using as an operand of the `sizeof` operator) is converted to pointer to its first element.

How to write correctly such a pointer for a multidimensional array?

Let's assume that you have a multidimensional array like

```
T a[N1][N2][N3][N4];
```

where `T` is some type and `N1`, `N2`, `N3`, `N4` are numbers of elements in sub-arrays. Then to get a pointer to the array element type you may rewrite the array like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3][N4];
```

So to get the pointer just substitute the record `a[N1]` for the record `*p` like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3][N4];
T ( *p )[N2][N3][N4] = a;
```

Now the pointer `p` points to the first element of the array a that has the type `T [N2][N3][N4]`.

Here are some examples

```
T ( a[N1] );
T ( *p ) = a; // that can be simplified like T *p = a;

T ( a[N1] )[N2];
T ( *p )[N2] = a;

T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3];
T ( *p )[N2][N3] = a;
```

and so on.

> In array the array name is pointer to first element's address

The C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

> Here we can think A as array of array, so A would point to 0th 1D
> array

Yes, a multidimensional array is an array elements of which are in turn arrays.

> So A+i would point to ith element of A

Yes, in the expression `A + i` the array designator is converted to pointer to its first element. So using the pointer arithmetic the source expression points to the i-th element of the array.

> *(A+i) would point to first element of ith element of A

The expression `*( A + i )`  yields the lvalue of the object pointed to by the expression `A + i`. If A is a two-dimensional array then the expression `*( A + i )` yields one dimensional array that is in the i-th "row" of the source array. The expression *( A + i ) is equivalent to the expression `A[i]`.

> Then in 2D array A+i address value should be same as *(A+i)

A + i is a pointed to the i-th element of the array A. If A is a two-dimensional array then the expression `*( A + i )` yields the i-th row of the array that is a one-dimensional array.  Used in expression this designator `*( A + I )` of a one-dimensional array in turn is converted yo pointer to its first element. So these two pointers `A + i` and `*( A + i )` after implicit conversion the last expression to a pointer will have the same value but different type.

So if you have

```
T A[N1][N2];
```

then the expression `A + i` has the type `T( * )[N2]`. Dereferencing the expression like `*( A + i )` you will get the i-th element of the original array that is a one-dimensional array of the type `T[N2]`. In turn this array designator used in expression is converted to its first element of the type T * and the both pointers `T( * )[N2]` and `T *` will have the same address within the memory extent occupied by the original array

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N1 = 3, N2 = 5 };
    int ( a[N1] )[N2];
    int ( * p )[N2] = a;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++)
    {
        printf( "a + %zu = %p, p + %zu = %p\n", 
                i, ( void * )( a + i ), i, ( void * )( p + i ) );
        printf( "*( a + %zu ) = %p, *(p + %zu ) = %p\n\n", 
                i, ( void * )*( a + i ), i, ( void * )*( p + i ) );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
a + 0 = 0x7ffda1063ab0, p + 0 = 0x7ffda1063ab0
*( a + 0 ) = 0x7ffda1063ab0, *(p + 0 ) = 0x7ffda1063ab0

a + 1 = 0x7ffda1063ac4, p + 1 = 0x7ffda1063ac4
*( a + 1 ) = 0x7ffda1063ac4, *(p + 1 ) = 0x7ffda1063ac4

a + 2 = 0x7ffda1063ad8, p + 2 = 0x7ffda1063ad8
*( a + 2 ) = 0x7ffda1063ad8, *(p + 2 ) = 0x7ffda1063ad8
```

Pay attention to that the value of the expression `a + 0` less than the value of the expression `a + 1` by `20` (or in hex by `0x14`) because `sizeof( *( a + i ) )` that is the same as `sizeof( int[5] )` is equal to `20`.